# I can't use or import Navigo in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've installed `navigo` and `@types/navigo` in my Typescript project using npm.

I want to use

```
new Navigo(null, true, "#!");
```

If not importing `navigo` I get the error

```
 TS2686: 'Navigo' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

When using `import Navigo from 'navigo';` I get the error

```
TS1192: Module '"path/node_modules/@types/navigo/index"' has no default export.
```

When using `import { Navigo } from 'navigo';` I get

```
TS2497: Module '"path/node_modules/@types/navigo/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

When using `import module = require("module");` I get

```
TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
```

What's wrong here?

Using this typedef
    https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/navigo/index.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this is an issue with the typings that you've installed. Diving into the source for Navigo it definitely uses a default export. The typings file exports using the `export =` syntax which you can [read more about here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require). It seems that these two are not directly compatible:

> ### `export =` and `import = require()`
>
> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an `exports` object which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the `exports` object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports `export =` to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.
>
> The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.
>
> When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

Comment: Thanks. So I file it as an issue on github?

Comment: @Asken What ever happened with your Navigo Typescript definition issue? I searched for it but did not see it in their Github issue tracker.

Comment: @Chris Frankly I wrote my own. I've stopped looking for shortcuts and only use the most common packages.